# How to get better at bullet chess

Tags: online-chess, bullet-chess

I am a bullet player. I play mostly on lichess and a little on chess.com. My peak rating in bullet is 1869. I have been trying to reach 1900 but I am unable to. I am also good at blitz chess, with a rating of 2518. But being good at blitz doesn't help me to get good at bullet. So, can anyone give me some tips on how I can get good at bullet?

I play 1+0, 1/2+0, 1/4+0 in bullet and 3+0 or 3+2 in blitz

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the time controls you play in bullet and blitz? For example, 1min and 45sec + 3sec are both bullet, but they are very different.

Comment: @Akavall I play 1+0, 1/2+0, 1/4+0 in bullet and 3+0 or 3+2 in blitz

Comment: I find it ridiculous that you are 2518 in 3+0 but can't get to 2000 in 1+0. If you really care about bullet so much, just queue for 2+0 games instead as that's basically the time control you're used to anyway.

Comment: With things like 1/4+0 it might be that your mouse speed is just not fast enough (I know my is certainly not.) Do you feel like you are losing on time most of those games? What would your rating be if you played just 1+0?

Comment: @Akavall In 1/2+0 and 1/4+0, I am losing more because of "dirty players". For eg. 1.b3 e5 2. Bb2 Ba3 3. Nc3(I am playing white) and I am already down a bishop. And this happens only because of premoves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a good bullet player, but will try to answer anyway. Apart from the usual suggestions (studying the game and working on tactics) the following ideas come to mind:

- In short time controls whose typicall completely neglected "non functional" aspects
  of chess can become more important, like time management, dealing
  with risk, dealing with hopeless positions, flagging and avoiding
  getting flagged. Observe a few videos of Nakamura or any other chess
  hero of your choice playing banter blitz/bullet, dealing with all of
  that. This has helped me a lot.
- In bullet flagging and getting flagged is integral part of the game.
  Get conscious of it. Whose who don't like that, should simply play other formats.
  E.g. if you are short of time you cannot afford
  to exchange into an lengthy endgame, since your opponent will simply
  start to flag you.
- Since time is short, all chess features which needs comparative more
  time to handle are affected negatively, at least this is what I
  firmly believe (I can not a good bullet player, since I have no real
  feeling for this problems). King safety gets much, much more
  important. The knight gets stronger in the endgame and can become
  extremly strong in the late endgame. Even the tinyiest advantages
  are usuall converted, if they can be exploited long enough.
- Bringing the opponent out of his comfort zone is *always* helpful, in
  bullet it can be deadly on the spot. E.g. against the Kings Indian
  attack (Nf3, g3, Bg2, 0-0) Nakamura plays sometimes in bullet d6,
  Nf6, Bd7, Qc8, Bh3 and then h5 with mating attack. I copied it and it
  scored deadly for me ;-).

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)